# combine string and table type in oracle stored procedure

Tags: arrays, oracle, concatenation

I am struck at a requirement in oracle stored procedure where I am getting data from type table in oracle that has 2 columns, now I need to extract on column and use it in stored procedure where clause.

For e.g I have a type array `EData` with 2 columns `ID` and `Name`.

I can use this in below way:

```
Select * from employees
where ID in (Select ID from table(EData))
```

But because of few constraints I am storing in a variable and executing using `Execute Immediate`

When I combine the code as a string I am getting error Cannot use the type table using string concatenation.

```
Query := 'Select ID from employees
where ID in (Select ID from' ||' table(EData))'
```

Later I will execute this as:

```
Execute Immediate Query into var_ID;
```

Above is not working, not sure how to overcome this.

Trying for few days now, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you declare a collection to store the all the ids from the table(Edata)? Then you can concat all the ids in the query later.

Comment: Because `execute immediate` doesn't know what the `EData` is: execute immediate has its own execution context, which is isolated from the caller unless you explicitly pass variable via binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense, but shows how to do it. Note lines #11 and 12.

```
SQL> create or replace type t_row is object (id number, name varchar2(20));
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> create or replace type t_tab is table of t_row;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_tab   t_tab;
  3    l_empno emp.empno%type;
  4    l_query varchar2(200);
  5  begin
  6    select t_row(deptno, dname)
  7      bulk collect
  8      into l_tab
  9      from dept;
 10
 11    l_query := 'select min(empno) from emp where deptno in (select deptno from table(:1))';
 12    execute immediate l_query into l_empno using l_tab ;
 13    dbms_output.put_line(l_empno);
 14  end;
 15  /
7369

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, will try solution and will update tomorrow as I am done with my work today.